# How can I extract both static data and formulae from excel?

Tags: excel

I am looking to extract both data and formulae from excel files. For example if there was an excel file with the following in cells A1, A2, A3:

```
2 3 5
```

Where 5 was a calculated field with the formula

```
=(A1 + A2)
```

What would be the best tool/approach to extract data and formulae in such a way that I get the static data and the calculated fields (and the relationship between them)?

Comment: where would you put the extract result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best would be to use VBA and .Formula property of Cells or Range.

For example:

```
If Sheet.Range("A1").Formula = Sheet.Range("A1").Value Then
    ' No formula
Else
    ' Has formula
End If
```

And the values are as such, formula and value.